# Available cipher suites iOS

Tags: ios, secure-transport

Did someone know why all cypher suite describe [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1550981-anonymous?language=objc) are indicate available in iOS 10+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's documentation error... I don't see anything in the header files indicating it's new as of iOS 10+

In addition, if you look at the doc pages for SSLCipherSuite, it list iOS 5.0+   ref: https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/sslciphersuite